# Propostional Logic Grammar for ParseKit

Tags: objective-c, grammar, parsekit

I'm trying to write a grammar for Parsekit to be used in my iphone app. Am I doing this correctly?

```
@start = wff;

wff = disjunction ('IMPLIES' | disjunction);
disjunction = conjunction ('OR' | conjunction)*;
conjunction = notexpression ('AND' | notexpression)*'
notexpression = ('NOT')+ primaryexpression;
primaryexpression = (literal | '(' wff ')');
literal = (A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N |O | P | Q | R | S | T |         U | V | W | X | Y | Z);
```

I am getting the error:

```
2012-11-26 10:41:06.348 SemanticTab[4092:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not build ClassName from token array for parserName: conjunction'
*** First throw call stack:
```

When trying to parse P OR Q?

Comment: Is the single quote instead of a semi colon at the end in: `notexpression ('AND' | notexpression)*'` a typo when posting your grammar? If not, perhaps that might be the cause?

Answer (score 2):

Developer of [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com) here.

I see two obvious problems:

1. The line with the `conjunction` production definition is terminated with a `'` (single quote). That should instead be a `;` (semi colon).
2. The definition for the `literal` production is not valid. There are no productions called `A`, `B`, `C`, etc. defined. However, if I understand your intention, the easier way to define `literal` is to use the built-in `Word` production:

   `literal = Word;`